# How do you style PHP code?

Tags: php, html, css

Okay. Let's say you have 2 radio buttons and a submit button. You select radio button 1, hit submit. It POSTS to the PHP page using code such as:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="http://localhost/quiz/index.php">
    <h2>Gender</h2>
    <label><p><input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1"> Male</p></label>
    <label><p><input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="2"> Female</p></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
</form>
```

Now on the PHP side, you have

```
$var = $_POST["myRadio"];
```

It stores it into a variable. Now, I can choose to `echo $var` ,but what if I wanted to print it in Arial, size 20, color: red, right justified. Now what if I wanted to do this with a LOT of data from the PHP code. How would I do that?

Comment: calm down. 1 by 1 question.

Comment: You can style anything on a web page with CSS.

Comment: `echo '<span class="sexyPants">'.$var.'</span>';` then write the css

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz Sorry, I created a new question, cause my last one everyone had trouble understanding, so I made this as clear as possible. And now I don't know why this is getting down voted

Comment: @Dagon But then you would have to in-line style every single echo?

Comment: um no, you are using classes for the style declaration

Comment: I see, makes sense. But sadly, probably going to be forced to delete this question, because apparently asking how to style PHP code is an opinion.

Comment: there a several dozen options. so yeah it is an opinion; not even sure if its a php or HTML question also.

Comment: @Dagon There are dozens of ways to do half the questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: well you have an answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend looking into [CSS Basics](http://www.cssbasics.com/).

Now to some code that will help you output the post. You mentioned you want to output `$var` but you also mention that there may be more post variables in the future. Let's begin.

Let's start with the [css](/questions/tagged/css) code.

First we visit [CSS Font Stack](http://www.cssfontstack.com/arial) to get my Arial. And behold, it also has a [font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) listed right there too, so we pick that up and set it to 20 right along with [font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).

```
.myClass{
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Now we need to change the darn color.

We visit [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) and see how they are doing this.

```
.myClass{
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red
}
```

Now we Google around looking for a way to align text in our element. We come across [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) and now we have

```
.myClass{
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red
    text-align: right;
}
```

Well that was pretty easy right?

Now we have to deal with this pesky [php](/questions/tagged/php) code don't we. Since you know how to echo we wont get into that. Let's see how we can assign this class to our element. We Google around a bit and find a [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/class-html-attribute/) link

So now we have a base html element of.

```
<div class='myClass'></div>
```

Well we have everything we need to echo I think. Let's try.

```
$var = $_POST["myRadio"];
echo "<div class='myClass'>$var</div>";
```

That seems to work fine so let's find out how we can list **each** value in a **for** loop, cleverly called a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

```
foreach($_POST as &$value) {
    echo "<div class='myClass'>$value</div>";
}
```

This outputs your values in your class formatting.

I hope this helps you get started. Keep in mind, I Googled every piece of this information whether I knew it or not and grabbed all of this straight from webpages listed on the first page of each Google search.

My Google logic in order ::

> css font arial
>
> css color
>
> css text justify
>
> html class
>
> php loop post

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes it more clear. It's hard because it's near impossible to find an answer if you don't know the question. It's much easier to search a "how to" on C++ or Java, but PHP, HTML, and all the web languages are melded into one monster.

Comment: I completely agree. I will update the answer on my logic googling these questions

Comment: Added my google logic that got me the answers I needed. I completely understand how difficult it can be to know what to look for. You are welcome to see my most downvoted question here due to never researching `echo` in [tag:PHP] to know that `<?=?>` is a shortcut. Not sure why anyone would have expected me to have researched `echo` or how difficult it is to google `<?=?>` ... Anyways, I digress